# Python TK.lift() and matplotlib. Lift won't execute "on time"

Tags: python, matplotlib, tk-toolkit

I'm a bit confused as to what's happening with my code.  I have a tk window that produces plots from data.  when I click the "ALL" button, all the plots should be made with their respective functions, and I'd like for the tk window to pop back to the top.  It does the lift command, but the other windows finish plotting after this command is finished.  the result is that the window is #3 or 4 or something.  How do I make sure lift runs when the other commands are finished?

```
def display_all(self):
    for x in range(0,len(self.thePlots)):
        # call all the plot functions
        --not included--
    self.lift()
```

Comment: Continuing my research, it seems like this may be a problem solved with threading?

Comment: How are you displaying the plots? Are you manually embedding them in Tkinter frames yourself, or are you using `plt.show`?

Comment: I'm using tkinter frames.